# how to display particular value in dropdown in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image]

when i click the edit button it should go the edit page[image]

when i want to edit the row with coursename="php"  in the drop down the course name should have selected as php since  the course name and the paper name,paper description are present in the different table i cant select the particular value in drop down

```
          if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
                  $table="papers";
                  $condition="paper_id=".$_GET["id"]."";
                  $select=selectlist($table,$condition);
                  $row=$list->fetch_array();
                  $table="courses";
                   $datalist=selectdata($table);
                   $data=Selectdata($table);
                   while($row1=$result->fetch_assoc())
                   {
                    $coursename=$row1['course_name'];


                  $courseid=$row['course_id'];
                   $paper=$row['paper_name'];
                  $paperdesc=$row['paper_description'];
                  $_SESSION['pid']=$row['paper_id'];  

                echo '<option value="'. $row1['course_id'].'" selected="'. $row1['course_id'].'=='.$courseid.'">'.$row1['course_name'].'</option>'; 
                  }
           }

                ?>
```

i have tried the above code i know the problem is with the "selected" please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost close to the answer.

Some modifications and you are done.

You need to **compare two values**.

The **value from database** (selected value) and the **value in loop**.

> Another suggestion is that we should not write any logic inside any
>   HTML tag.
>
> HTMLs/Templates are just for printing output to screen.
>
> We should first evaluate all conditions and then print HTML.

[selected Reference](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select)

Change

```
echo '<option value="'. $row1['course_id'].'" selected="'. $row1['course_id'].'=='.$courseid.'">'.$row1['course_name'].'</option>';
```

To:

```
$selected = ($row1['course_id'] == $courseid) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
echo '<option value="'. $row1['course_id'].'" ' . $selected . '>'.$row1['course_name'].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `while loop`:

```
<?php
while($row1=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $coursename=$row1['course_name'];
    $courseid=$row['course_id'];
    $paper=$row['paper_name'];
    $paperdesc=$row['paper_description'];
    $_SESSION['pid']=$row['paper_id'];  

    if($courseid == $row1['course_id']) {
        echo '<option value="'. $row1['course_id'].'" selected>'.$row1['course_name'].'</option>'; 
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'. $row1['course_id'].'" >'.$row1['course_name'].'</option>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following:

```
while($row1=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
        $coursename=$row1['course_name'];
        $courseid=$row['course_id'];
        $paper=$row['paper_name'];
        $paperdesc=$row['paper_description'];
        $_SESSION['pid']=$row['paper_id'];  
        $selected="";
        if($row['course_id']==$course_id)
        {
            $selected="selected";
        }
       echo '<option value="'. $row1['course_id'].'" $selected>'.$row1['course_name'].'</option>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes your job done

```
while($row1=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $coursename=$row1['course_name'];
  $courseid=$row['course_id'];
  $paper=$row['paper_name'];
  $paperdesc=$row['paper_description'];
  $_SESSION['pid']=$row['paper_id']; 

  echo "<option value = '{$row1['course_id']}'";
  if ($courseid == $row1['course_id'])
    echo "selected = 'selected'";
  echo ">{$row1['course_name']}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use ternary operator inside option)

```
  echo '<option value="'. $row1['course_id'].'" selected="'. $row1['course_id'].'=='.$courseid.'">'.$row1['course_name'].'</option>';
```

change into

```
 <option value="<?= $row1['course_id'] ?>" <?= $row1['course_id']==$courseid? "selected":""?> > <?= $row1['course_name'] ?> </option>';
```